# succesive mean quantization(SMQT)

Tags: matlab

I am trying to do succesive mean quantization transform. And ı stuck the condition while making D0 and D1.ı dont know what ı should put in if the condition is false . (making 0 is not the solution because its changes the new matrix of mean).

Let x be a data point and D(x) be a set of |D(x)| = D data
points. The value of a data point will be denoted V(x).

D0(x) = {x | V(x) ≤ mean(V(x)), ∀x ∈ D}

D1(x) = {x | V(x) > mean(V(x)), ∀x ∈ D}

where D0(x) propagates left and D1(x) right in the binary
tree.

[Article about SMQT](http://btu.se/fou/forskinfo.nsf/17e96a0dab8ab6a1c1257457004d59ab/2660bccb72bce3ccc125714d004828c1/%24file/successive%20mean...pdf)

Is there anyone who studied smqt before or any idea to solve this problem.
thanks.

Comment: I created an article explaining the SMQT, improving the algorithm (faster), and releasing a C++ implementation: http://www.toptal.com/algorithms/successive-mean-quantization-transform

Answer (score 0, accepted):

D0 and D1 are arrays

D0=V(V<=mean(V(:)));

D1=V(V>mean(V(:)));

Comment: Do you have the `smqt` source in MATLAB? if yes can you give it to me?

Comment: Which part did u stuck ?

Comment: If u say where did u stuck maybe ı can help @EN20

Comment: I develop smqt but not solve my problem.
I am going to do an article project and I have problem with smqt
Can you give me your email address?

Comment: if u give me your mail i can reach u and help ı hope. @EN20

Comment: My email address is Vahid.Forghani@gmail.com